# How to delete an element inside array of a nested document in C# Mongodb strongly typed driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using the official C# MongoDb strongly typed driver version 2.5.0 to interact with MongoDB.

Consider the following classes:

```
public class Author
{

    public Author()
    {

    }

    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string BirthDate { get; set; }

    public string ScientificDegree { get; set; }

    public Library Library { get; set; }
}

public class Library
{
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }

    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }

    [BsonDefaultValue(0)]
    public int ReadCount { get; set; }

}
```

How to delete a book using it's id from the author library? Here is my code to delete an element from the array directly.

```
var field = new ExpressionFieldDefinition<Library, List<Book>>(library => library.Books);

var bookFilter = Builders<Book>.Filter.Eq(book => book.Id, bookId);

var update = Builders<Library>.Update.PullFilter(field, bookFilter);

//How to apply the update to the author using author id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get stored `Library`and perform changes to that `Library` object and update it back to document. Another way you can make use of `PullFilter` to delete it

```
var update = Builders<Author>.Update.PullFilter(x=>x.Library.Books,Builders<Book>.Filter.Eq(x=>x.id,bookId));
db.Author.UpdateOneAsync(x => x.Id.Equals(autherId), update).Result;
```

`db.Author` is collection instance

Comment: This solution is inconvenient, I want to find and update the Library object directly in one operation, unless MongoDB doesn't support this functionality.

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995762/nested-array-pull-query-using-c-sharp-mongodb-driver/33015462

Comment: The array in the referred question is a direct element in the document, which is not the same in my case as the array is an element of a nested document, thanks for the reply.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: How to update a property of an element of the array?