# MongoDB: Delete the element with the latest date from an array

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have document like so:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56bba46fd827382936d52c3a"),
    "grades" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2012-05-08T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 12
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2016-02-10T21:04:49.691Z"),
            "grade" : "A*",
            "score" : 10
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2016-02-10T21:11:24.368Z"),
            "grade" : "A*",
            "score" : 10
        }
    ],
}
```

I want to delete the entry for grades with the latest date using the C# driver.  The only way I can see to do this is to replace the entire array with a new array.

Is there a better way?

Comment: You can use $pull check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30145663/3432471

Comment: Cheers @MaDeRkAn, how would I do the max date query though?  Can it be done in a single transaction?

Comment: I think you should unwind grades first, then sort by date then you should pulll with document.id and grades.date. I'm not familiar new c# driver So I'm not sure you can do this with driver. You may need use aggreation.

Comment: This is actually posed as a MongoDB university course homework question (more or less), so it really is not desirable to post answers here as you are meant to work it out for yourself. Your own comments seem to have suggested that you have at least worked out how to identify the entry which is indeed part of the problem. And no, there is no way to ask to remove the "last date" in a single statement. Of course `$pull` would actually be employed once you identify which date to remove.

Comment: @BlakesSeven that's just coincidence.  I'm registered for the next MongoDB University though!  I guess I'll be struggling with that question.  It's actually for a set of demo methodfs I'm writing at https://bitbucket.org/BanksySan/mongodbdemo

Comment: Not really your fault as the course material uses sample data that is posted and freely available along with other demonstrations. I guess in essence if you looked at the question as *"Is there an operator to match the max element of an array?"* then it's both yes and no. There is a way to do it, but not with something that returns the matched position in a single pass. Nor would "position" matter in the context of atomically removing an element from an array. But still not keen to post responses that would essentially result in a "lookup" answer for a course question.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I can see why you wouldn't want to do that.  I'm actually writing it as an example of where MongoDB isn't very good.  That being, complex data manipulation.  My strategy for the implementation in the office is to have immutable documents as much as possible.  If a case like this arose I'd be suggesting adding a `deleted` element, rather than actually deleting.

Comment: I'm still a bit tempted to reveal a little something that would not be in the course content though. The [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) operator changes behaviour in MongoDB 3.2. Previously this worked only with single values, but now it can handle an expression that is an "array". So if you looked around at similar operators that could just extract one field from the array! Without letting on too much. There should be enough hints in all comments from everyone so far as to work out the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: @BlakesSeven, I'll have a poke and report back!