# Delete an object of array list in mongdb

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have collection, contain an array of objects and I want to delete one object by filter inside this array example:

```
"ProductsImages" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c6fc524c324ac0e7497b6c0"), 
        "Namefile" : "Bild-4.png", 
        "Urls" : "https://fares.blob.core.windows.net/fares2/Bild-4.png"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c6fc52cc324ac0e7497b6c1"), 
        "Namefile" : "KINGSTON-BAY-704668-logo.png", 
        "Urls" : "https://fares.blob.core.windows.net/fares2/KINGSTON-BAY-704668-logo.png"
    }
],
```

so i want to delete first one which contain a "Namefile" : "Bild-4.png" in mongodb shell, or C# monogodb drive and thanks for your help.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/15122017/195509 - it sounds like using the $pull operator is what you're looking for. For an example using the C# driver, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30145663/195509.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB .Net driver 2.0 Pull (remove element)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141958/mongodb-net-driver-2-0-pull-remove-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this update query

```
db.collName.update({"ProductsImages.Namefile": "Bild-4.png"},{$pull: {"ProductsImages": {"Namefile": "Bild-4.png"}}})
```

> Note: Update the first filter condition as required